# Passing a URL through jQuery with awkward routing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am familiar with how to pass data through a url through jQuery, to my ASP.NET MVC controllers, but I was writing some code today and came upon an interesting URL that I cannot quite figure out how to format...

The route reads something like this ...

```
///////////////////////////////////////////
// route: /member/{0}/characters
///////////////////////////////////////////
public ActionResult Characters(int member){
 // get the list of the member's characters
}
```

So the URL would actually have the 'parameter' right in the middle. This is curious to me, because I'm not sure how this translates to the jQuery "data" property on `$.ajax`. I would normally set it like this ....

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/member/characters',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { member: 1 }
}).done(function (data) { viewModel.set("Player", data); });
```

But that can't seem to work in this situation. I suppose I could do some very hokey string formatting, but I am hoping to do this a bit more cleanly...

Does anyone have suggestions for handling odd routes like this?

Comment: Shouldn't you just pass the data in the querystring? `url: '/member/1/characters',` and not send the data? This is just a get request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use the `data` parameter since that only sets query string attributes.  Your value is actually part of the path, so you'll need to do something different.  Try using `@Url.Action` to generate a correct URL, and omit the `data` parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Characters", "Member", new { member = 1 })',
}).done(function (data) { viewModel.set("Player", data); });
```

This will not work if your member id is dynamically chosen from javascript.

To do that, you'll have to manually create your url:

```
var url = '/member/' + memberId + '/characters';
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. I was hoping there was a smarter way to do this, but it seems hokey strings is the only solution. Thank you for your time.